# Fail to install pymysqlclient for python3.10.11 (via pip3) in cnetOS 7.9 x64

Tags: python-3.x, django, centos, centos7

I Fail to install pymysqlclient for python3.10.11 (via pip3) in cnetOS 7.9 x64

```
Looking in indexes: http://mirrors.aliyun.com/pypi/simple/
Collecting mysqlclient
  Using cached http://mirrors.aliyun.com/pypi/packages/79/33/996dc0ba3f03e2399adc91a7de1f61cb14b57ebdb4cc6eca8a78723043cb/mysqlclient-2.2.4.tar.gz (90 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [24 lines of output]
      Trying pkg-config --exists mysqlclient
      Command 'pkg-config --exists mysqlclient' returned non-zero exit status 1.
      Trying pkg-config --exists mariadb
      Command 'pkg-config --exists mariadb' returned non-zero exit status 1.
      Trying pkg-config --exists libmariadb
      Command 'pkg-config --exists libmariadb' returned non-zero exit status 1.
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/home/code/nrcoa/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "/home/code/nrcoa/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "/home/code/nrcoa/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-hww7nl84/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 325, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-hww7nl84/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 295, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-hww7nl84/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 311, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 155, in <module>
        File "<string>", line 49, in get_config_posix
        File "<string>", line 28, in find_package_name
      Exception: Can not find valid pkg-config name.
      Specify MYSQLCLIENT_CFLAGS and MYSQLCLIENT_LDFLAGS env vars manually
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.
```

I try to deploy my Django5.0.2 project on my centOS cloud server.But I failed during migrate venv with require.txt below

```
asgiref==3.7.2
Django==5.0.2
mysqlclient==2.2.4
pillow==10.2.0
sqlparse==0.4.4
typing_extensions==4.9.0
tzdata==2023.4
```

All modules are installed successfully except mysqlclient

HOPE FOR ANY IDEA

I tried many solution searche online,
INCLUDING install python3-devel or dev and so on
but failed